# DataMapper require addressable error when used with Google-API-Client

Tags: ruby, rubygems, datamapper, google-api-client

I am working on a project which uses DataMapper and the google-api gems. When try to run the project with shotgun or thin I get an error. Running bundler or the project raises an error stating that DataMapper uses addressable version 2.4.1 and the google-api-client gem uses addressable 2.4.5 (The versions might not be exactly correct as I am writing this from memory).

I am fairly new to ruby, but I would guess this sort of conflict is common enough that there might be an idiomatic way to handle this. I obviously could fork either project and try to update/rollback the addressable conflict but this does seem like the right way to go about it.

update::
Here is the result of trying to require the google-api gem in irb after requiring dataMapper

`1.9.3p194 :004 > require 'google/api_client'
    Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate google-api-client-0.4.6, because addressable-2.2.6      conflicts with addressable (>= 2.3.2)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no idiomatic way to handle this. The datamapper dependency to addressable is just to old and bundler cannot find a compatible version.

As far as I understand the changes from the addressable [Changelog](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), there was no breaking API change since addressable-2.2.6, that affects dm-core. Datamapper could be updated to use a more recent version of addressable.

The development of the datamapper 1.x branch had stopped. We are actively working on datamapper-2.0.

In the "release-1.2" branch of datamapper on github the dependency was already updated. You can use this branch via your Gemfile:

```
gem 'dm-core', :git => 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core', :branch => 'release-1.2'
```

This branch declares compatibility to addressable 2.x but greater than 2.3. You should be able to resolve your dependency issue using this branch.

Comment: Well, there are breaking changes from 2.2.x to 2.3.x, but very few people are likely to notice them. I don't think the usage in DataMapper is affected at all.

Comment: Thx, I updated my answer to be more explicit about API breaks.

Comment: Yeah, generally, my preference for declaring an Addressable dependency would be to use `>=` against the lowest version of Addressable that will get the job done. But if you absolutely must be paranoid about breaking changes, then use `~> 2.2` or `~> 2.3`, with a strong preference for the former unless you are relying on the old deprecated `query_values` behavior. Avoid using `~> 2.2.6` or any other 3-digit `~>` version requirement like the plague. That causes serious problems all the time.

Comment: As dm-core is in maintainance mode and we devote all or our relatively small resources to datamapper-2.0. The currently used version requirement for addressable ```~> 2.3``` should be enough for the next month. I'd prefer to get dm-1.x integration tested again, but we do not have the resources to port this stuff to travis or to make the Jenkins setup pass again.

Comment: Is there a different repo for 2.0? Went looking for it, but didn't see any info on it.

Comment: DataMapper 2.0 is build around several libraries with a single reponsibility and a sharp interface. See dkub/veritas, datamapper/dm-mapper, datamapper/dm-session on github.